# What's an efficient way to turn a bunch of custom-edited Greasemonkey script @includes into user-includes?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I use [Webcomic Reader](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/ameboide/Webcomic_Reader) very heavily, and have for a few years now. Before Greasemonkey added user includes, I built up a fair collection of custom `@include` rules in my local copy.

This was a little annoying to copy into the new version of the file every time I wanted to update, but I managed. Now, though, I'm thinking that's really kind of fragile and I should try to migrate to the user include feature, but I have not the slightest desire to manually copy and paste 307 lines* one by one into Greasemonkey's option input boxes.

Any suggestions for automating this process?

*Per Notepad++'s selection count; it might be off by one I suppose.

Comment: All of those must either be stored in a config file or the registry.  If you can find the file/registry key you **might** be able to copy and paste the whole list in at once.

Comment: @cybernard: GM uses SQLite for its userscript stuff. I've fiddled around very slightly with that but it's frankly a bit intimidating to have to feel around with DDL-SQL on a strange CLI. E: However, that is a good point, and it might be just as good as the alternative. Something to think about.

Comment: GM only uses SQLite for `GM_setValue` data. General config is XML.  Tampermonkey is all SQLite.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I am corrected. I'll give your suggestion a try in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greasemonkey stores script control stuff in its `config.xml` file.  You can edit this file to affect the changes you want.

1. Go to your [Firefox Profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox).
2. From there enter the `gm_scripts` folder.
3. Shut down Firefox (helps guard against accidentally trashing your profile, or the GM install).
4. With a suitable editor (Notepad++, TextPad, Emacs, etc.), edit the `config.xml` file.
5. Find the `<Script...>  ... </Script>` section for your userscript.
6. For just the `<Include> ... </Include>` lines that you want to convert, replace `Include` with `UserInclude` (2 instances per line).
7. Save the changes and restart Firefox.
8. Done!

Answer (score 0):

I do have one idea for this, but it's ugly as sin, almost: SendKeys, probably from a PowerShell script, fed with the @includes so far. Will expand on this if no other answer given.